# Function to return all events in a certain date

Tags: excel, function, datetime, vba

I have a table that has a start date, end date, and then event name

I would like to be able to look up a date and see if it falls between the start and end date and then pull in all the event names that meet those criteria

For example

```
start   end    name
1/1     1/7    Event1
1/5     1/8    Event2
1/6     1/6    Event3
```

If i wanted a date of 1/5,  the return value would be **Event1; Event2**

```
Function DateEventLookup(eventdate As Long, startrng As Range, endrng As Range, pIndex As Long)

' eventdate is the lookup , startrng is the first array, endrng is the second array, pindex is the column to return

Dim rng As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim xResult As String


xResult = ""
For Each rng In startrng
    If rng.Value <= eventdate Then
        For Each rng2 In endrng
          If rng2.Value >= eventdate Then
        xResult = xResult & "," & rng2.Offset(0, pIndex - 1)
        End If
Next
End If
Next


DateEventLookup = xResult
End Function
```

I keep getting N/A# so i am not sure how to correct this with the second criteria

EDIT #1

I took a combo of two answers. However I am still getting dupes

```
Public Function EventList(starts As Range, ends As Range, events As Range, d As Date) As String
    Dim N As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim P As Object
    Set P = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")


    N = Cells(Rows.Count, starts.Column).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To N
        If CDate(starts(i)) <= d And CDate(ends(i)) >= d Then P.Item(events(i)) = 1


        'EventList = EventList & "; " & events(i)
    Next i
    EventList = Join(P.keys, ", ")

End Function
```

Not sure how to fix this I tried adding in a

If NOT p.exists(events(i)) then ADD

but I am getting an N/A# now

Comment: Please give an example of how you are calling the function. You are trying to do a numerical comparison on a string.

Comment: the lookup value is in serial form, and the dates should be serial too. They are just formatted to the M/DD/YYYY

Comment: Are you saying the the serial numbers are strings, so you cant use a > or < on them?

Comment: A date is just a number in Excel. How can it interpret `If rng <= eventdate`?

Comment: Eventdate is a serial number of a date, so it should just be a number too

Comment: `eventdate As String`

Comment: Oh wow.... so long?

Comment: Or Date? Also you don't want a nested loop. You want to cycle through the start date only and check the corresponding cell to the right.

Comment: Got it.  So I can get rid of endrng as an input and then for the second criteria just use rnge.Offset(0, 1)?

Comment: Yes, I have suggested an answer below which also avoids duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a very simple alternative:

```
Public Function EventList(starts As Range, ends As Range, events As Range, d As Date) As String
    Dim N As Long, i As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, starts.Column).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To N
        If CDate(starts(i)) <= d And CDate(ends(i)) >= d Then EventList = EventList & "; " & events(i)
    Next i
    EventList = Mid(EventList, 2)

End Function
```

[image]

Comment: is there a way to remove dupes?

Comment: @RPr  I don't see any dups?

Comment: sorry in the data I have there are a few that over lap date wise and have the same name I am trying the scriping.dictionary, but it doesnt seem to be working

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Range.Value, not the range itself.

(This is untested, but I thnk the change will make it work)

```
For Each rng In startrng
    If rng.value <= eventdate Then
        For Each rng2 In endrng
          If rng2.value >= eventdate Then
        xResult = xResult & "," & rng2.Offset(0, pIndex - 1)
        End If
Next
```

Comment: I don't think it will because value is the default property of the range object so that you don't need to specify it (here at least), although it is good practice to do so.

Comment: Yea I keep getting an na with this. Not sure if i have the Next
End If
Next     wrong at the end or something

Comment: SRJ, you're right, I had a bit more time to look into it, the problem is eventdate being a string.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a suggestion, called, e.g. =DateEventLookup(DATE(2018,1,5),A2:A4,B2:B4,3) You'll have to fiddle with the arguments as don't know how your data are laid out.

```
Function DateEventLookup(eventdate As Date, startrng As Range, endrng As Range, pIndex As Long)

' eventdate is the lookup , startrng is the first array, endrng is the second array, pindex is the column to return

Dim rng As Range
Dim d As Object

Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

For Each rng In startrng
    If rng <= eventdate Then
        If rng.Offset(, 1) >= eventdate Then
            d.Item(rng.Offset(0, pIndex - 1)) = 1
        End If
    End If
Next

DateEventLookup = Join(d.keys, ",")

End Function
```

Comment: thanks, can you walk me through the use of the create object line and this line   d.Item(rng.Offset(0, pIndex - 1)) = 1?

I am assuming it stores values in the created "scripting.dictionary" object and then you join them all at the end?

Comment: Read eg https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/ for a guide to dictionaries. They're a bit like arrays or collections in that you can store data (as key/item pairs), and you can if values already exist. Here the event is added as a key when the requirements are met and the result outputs the keys as a string separated by commas.

Comment: and you can if values already exist----   is this supposed to be can't*?

Comment: Should have read "can check if values already exist", although in the way I have used it above it will automatically overwrite. Without this you could end up with e.g. "Event1, Event2, Event1"

Comment: whats does the = 1 at the end do, remove the dupes?